# How to display another page during technical work?

Tags: nginx

When  need to stop nginx in order to make some changes,  need to display a page with a message that technical work is underway. At the moment, when I stop nginx on the page, my loader from the application simply scrolls.

What needs to be done to display another page when stopped?

```
...
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

...
```

Answer (score 0):

you will use if file found .

set file before your technical work .

if found , use redirect to anther page

```
    location / {

        set $cacheFile /www/technical.work;

        if (-f $cacheFile) {

return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

        }

    }
```